# How to count rows form mysql with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Trying to get total count of rows using variable in sql query but not able to get that can anyone here help me with this ?

```
<?php

    $business = $value['business_name'];

    //echo $business;

    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM listings_reviews WHERE business_name = '$business'";

    $result = $conn-> query($sql);

    $row = $result -> fetch_assoc();

    //print_r ($row) ;

    $rating = implode($row);

    echo $rating;
    ?>
```

Comment: Format your code properly and explain what you want to do. Count the amount of Rows? Count the Amount of the Values of the Rows or what do you want to do?

Comment: @Vikas Temgire you question is half clear do you want to count rows `WHERE  business_name = '$business'" ` or you want to count the amount. Edit the question again

Comment: Yes bro, But I got that solution but thank you for your interest....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give an alias to your `COUNT(*)` in the SQL, for example, here I have aliased it to `cnt`.

Then in PHP you can identify clearly the variable of the `$row` array

```
$business = $value['business_name'];

//echo $business;

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM listings_reviews WHERE business_name = '$business'";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rating = $row["cnt"];
}

echo $rating;
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$q = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS `all_lines` FROM `table_name`';
$record = $db->query_first($q);

$all_lines = $record['all_lines'];
```

Comment: Where is `query_first()` in any standard php mysql extension

Comment: It is just example based on php mysql class from ricocheting.com. If you want to use plain php replace function query_first() to mysql_query().

Answer (score 0):

Group by business name:

```
$business = $value['business_name'];

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS c FROM listings_reviews WHERE business_name = '$business' GROUP BY business_name";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

$row = $result ->fetch_assoc();

$listingsByBusiness = $row['c'];
```

For reference, see

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html